# Play iOS notification sound in silent mode in background

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to play remote notification sound on iOS in silent mode when my app in background. For this I'm using content-available flag in notification payload. So when notification arrive it trigger didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler in my app delegate and sound is played. The problem is when content-available flag installed push notification get low priority and delivery time growing significantly. Is there are other ways to play notification sound in silent mode when app in background?

Comment: 'content-available' is meant only for silent notifications & by default will make pushes low priority. Is  there any specific reason that you can't use standard push notifications? (where User intervention is required to accept notification).

Comment: I need to play sound when push arrive even in silent mode. So I can't use standard notification because there'll be no sound when device is muted

Comment: Oh. AFAIK, there is no way you can make a silent notification as high priority. Its not allowed. The only way I see here is Pushkit. But that's meant only for Voip Pushes. (If your app is not Voip related, you should not use it).